# Fancy Footnote Rule

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes

I am trying to use `tikz` to create a more visually interesting vertical rule to separate the footnotes in my document. Here is my re-definition (code from the `soulpos` package documentation).

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{% 
  \kern -3pt\begin{tikzpicture}% 
  \draw[ color=black, line width=1.5pt, decorate, 
         decoration= {random steps, segment length=1.5mm, amplitude=.5pt}] 
         (0,0) -- +(\textwidth,0); 
   \end{tikzpicture}% 
   \kern 1.5pt% 
}
```

It seems to correctly align the first footnote rule (horizontally), but all the subsequent lines in the chapter are indented. How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Please provide an MWE as requested for your previous question. Also, do you mean 'horizontal' rather than 'vertical'?

Comment: My two cents; don't do it. It's not interesting after two pages (in presentations it is kinda fun though).

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `\noindent`

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[ color=black, line width=1.5pt, decorate, decoration= {random steps, segment length=1.5mm, amplitude=.5pt}] (0,0) --
+(\textwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\vskip2pt}
```

I have added an extra `\vskip2pt` just to make things neater.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OR]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[ color=black, line width=1.5pt, decorate, decoration= {random steps, segment length=1.5mm, amplitude=.5pt}] (0,0) --
+(\textwidth,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip2pt}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{One}
  \lipsum[1]\footnote{foot one}
  \clearpage
  \lipsum[2]\footnote{foot 2}\footnote{foot 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]